# how to use ggplot through Azure ML R Script

Tags: r, ggplot2, azure-machine-learning-service

In data exploration phrase, I need some visualization to check the relationship between data columns. I have tried Azure ML built-in visualization and felt it's limited. R ggplot allows me to choose the chart I want and do some customization.

I am very new in using Azure ML. When I am trying Azure ML R script and type:

```
library("ggplot2")

p <- ggplot(train, aes(x= Item_Visibility, y = Item_Outlet_Sales)) +
geom_point(size = 2.5, color = "navy") + xlab("Item Visibility") + ylab("Item Outlet Sales")
```

Cannot find where is my visualization... It is not in visualization result, neither in log ourput
I have also tried Azure ML built-in plot(), it cannot find the column in my dataset...

So, is there anyway, when I am using ggplot in Azure ML R Script, I can find the visualization results?

Comment: Possibly this is related to the FAQ about grid graphics. What happens if you call `print(p)`?

Comment: I tried this too, it gave me an error and points to "print", indicating there is no print function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the visualization. Just put the code in AzureML Studio Execute R Script module will be fine.
After the code has been executed successfully, right click Execute R Script module, and choose R device, the visualization is there

[image: ggplot through AzureML R Script]